# Error during compile c++ file through Android NDK

Tags: c, android-ndk

I try to compile some library and get error:

```
In file included from *************************:
F:/include/strutils.h:40:37: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'dest'
 extern void *mempcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t n);
```

This is strutils.h :

```
#ifndef HAVE_MEMPCPY
extern void *mempcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t n);
#endif
```

What wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not recognize the word restrict.

If it is a C file, you probably need to specify a command-line switch to tell it recognize the C99 keywords.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Alternatively,

```
#define restrict
```

or probably

```
#define restrict __restrict__
```

if *strutils.h* is included from a *.cpp* file: 
[C++ does not have standard support for `restrict`, but many compilers have equivalents which usually work in both C++ and C, such as the GNU Compiler Collection `__restrict__`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict)

Comment: Where exactly #define restrict and what define ?